# iPhone physics engine for fluid/water simulation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, box2d

I'm about to start developing a game that's main feature revolves around 2D water simulation. I have thought about starting with Box2D and designing water in that engine, but I'm not sure if it would be efficient, and I don't have any experience with Box2D.

It would be great if there was an engine with good fluid simulation built in. If not, where should I start? I have been searching around for a while and still don't really have a good place to begin.

The water is only going to take up at most 10% of the screen at a time, and my goal is 40 FPS on the 3GS and 45+ on the iPhone 4. Just rough numbers.

Comment: I'm also very interested in that subject. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Not yet. There is hardly anything good for this anywhere as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

actually you have to trick to make something looking smooth.
Disney's "Where is my water?" app, is awesome for this, they make a first render of large balls and then create a water mask which serve as a filter to make this appears like a real stream. This will visually be much better even if physically it is more approximative than simulating hundreds of thousands of drops.

Take a look on [this example](http://www.patrickmatte.com/stuff/physicsLiquid/) to see what I mean

I never pushed Box2D to its limits but in my opinion it should be adapted enough for this usage.

Comment: Really nice solution. When the fluid is not moving though it can look strange.